# C: how to avoid repeating popen when output parsed twice?

Tags: c, linux, scanf, popen

I want to parse output of [`popen(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), but it looks like I have to repeat `popen()` call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int v1, v2, v3;
    char unused[255];
    FILE *f;

    f = popen("ip -V", "r");

    fscanf(f, "ip utility, iproute2-v%d.%d.%d-%s", &v1, &v2, &v3, unused);
    printf("%d.%d.%d (%s)\n", v1, v2, v3, unused);

    f = popen("ip -V", "r"); // TODO: how to avoid repeating popen()?
    fscanf(f, "ip utility, iproute2-%d.%d.%d", &v1, &v2, &v3);
    printf("%d.%d.%d\n", v1, v2, v3);

    pclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Testing on this version:

```
$ ip -V
ip utility, iproute2-5.8.0
```

*Without* repeating, it keeps the old value:

```
$ ./fscanf-popen
32764.-1446225616.0 ()
32764.-1446225616.0
```

*With* repeating it handles it correctly:

```
$ ./fscanf-popen
32765.1933255568.0 ()
5.8.0
```

`fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);` and `rewind(f);` does not help.
I have to miss something obvious.

Comment: If we want to use the data twice, you should store it.

Comment: In the first call you have `iproute2-v%d.%d.%d` with an extra `v` in the format string. That `v` is not in the second attempt. I suggest you check what the [`fscanf` calls ***return***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: ...but in your case you just need to make sure you consume the `,` in your format string, and check the values returned by `scanf`.

Comment: As for your question, read all of the output, until `EOF`, into an in-memory buffer. Then parse that buffer instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I removed the check code in order to simplify the example. But even with the code, there are more attempts needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the output of the pipe using `fscanf()`, which consumes the input from the stream until it satisfies the specified format. For this reason without a further `fscanf` will just read any new data present in the stream. What you need, instead is to store the input into a string (an array of `char`s).

In order to accomplish this task you can just use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) in order to read the whole line. In this way you'll always be able to pass the stored string to `sscanf()`, or to perform any other parsing action required to retrieve the values the string contains:

```
char buf[1000];

f = popen("ip -V", "r");

if( f )
{
    char *ret = fgets(buf, 1000, f);

    if( ret )
    {
        sscanf(buf, "ip utility, iproute2-v%d.%d.%d-%s", &v1, &v2, &v3, unused); // or any other proper parsing action
        printf("%d.%d.%d (%s)\n", v1, v2, v3, unused);
    }

    /* ... */
  
    pclose(f);
}
```

`fgets` reads just one line (preserving trailing newline). If you need to read N lines, just iterate repeating it until it returns `NULL`.